# How can i format an LDAP Filter that includes special characters? ('Classic' ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, ldap, ldap-query

I'm having trouble retrieving information via LDAP for certain groups I have the DistinguishedName of.
The issue seems to relate to them having special characters.

Here are two examples, one working, one not:
All in Test Group
All in 463\"567y\\22\"¤&/2#%&! Test Group

and their dn's:
CN=All in Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=some,DC=test,DC=com
CN=All in 463\"567y\\22\"¤&/2#%&! Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=some,DC=test,DC=com

I know the dn's are correct, as I retrieve them from a users managedObjects attribute, and have verified them in AD and also using ADSI Edit.

Now, onto what code I am using to retrieve the information, note that this code works fine on the group without special characters:

```
Dim strGroupdisplayName, strGroupsAMAccountname, strGroupmail


Function GetGroupInfofromDN(group_str)
on error resume next
DIM objGroup, objDNNamespace, strLDAPGroup
strLDAPGroup = "LDAP://" + group_str
Set objDNNamespace = GetObject("LDAP:")
Set objGroup = objDNNamespace.OpenDSObject(strLDAPGroup, strADUsername, strADPassword,0)
objGroup.GetInfo
strGroupdisplayName = ""
strGroupsAMAccountname = ""
strGroupmail = ""
strGroupdisplayName = ObjGroup.Get("displayName")
strGroupsAMAccountname = ObjGroup.Get("sAMAccountname")
strGroupmail = ObjGroup.Get("mail")
set objGroup = Nothing
End Function
```

As for what I've tried... I've tried encoding the groups to URI format, I've tried replacing special characters with their escaped equivalents:

```
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "\", "\5c")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "(", "\28")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "|", "\7c")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "<", "\3c")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "/", "\2f")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, ")", "\29")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "=", "\3d")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "~", "\7e")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "&", "\26")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, ">", "\3e")
strTemp = replace(strTemp, "*", "\2a")
```

I've also tried via regex to pull out the CN= section and only alter that.

Quite frankly, i'm at a loss as to what I should do here.

I've also tried another method:

```
set connAD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connAD.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
connAD.Properties("User ID") = strADUsername 
connAD.Properties("Password") = strADPassword
connAD.Properties("Encrypt Password") = true
connAD.Open

Function getADUserInfo(strUID)

    strGeneralLookupError = false
    strBase = "<LDAP://DC=SOME,DC=TEST,DC=COM>"
    strFilter = "(distinguishedName=" & strUID & ")" 
    strAttributes = "cn, mail, company, givenName, sn, ADsPath, name, sAMAccountName, telephoneNumber, distinguishedName, managedObjects"
    strScope = "subtree"    
    strFullCommand = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";" & strScope
    set rsADUserInfo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    set rsADUserInfo = connAD.Execute(strFullCommand)
    set getADUserInfo = rsADUserInfo
    set rsADUserInfo = Nothing
End Function

Sub getUserData(p_strUserID)

    strADLookupSuccess = true
    set rsUserData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    set rsUserData = getADUserInfo(p_strUserID)
    if not rsUserData.EOF then
        strUserADsPath = rsUserData("ADsPath")
        strUserdistinguishedName = rsUserData("distinguishedName")
    else
        strADLookupSuccess = false
    end if
    rsUserData.Close
    set rsUserData = Nothing
End Sub

dim strUserADsPath, strUserdistinguishedName, rsUserData, rsADUserInfo, strADLookupSuccess
getUserData("CN=All in 463\"567y\\\\22\"¤&/2\#%&! Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=some,DC=test,DC=com")

connAD.Close
set connAD = Nothing
```

Any suggestions? All the things I've read so far make mention to special characters, but escaping them does not seem to work...

Also, this is Classic ASP, running against Windows Server 2008 r2-based domain.

**EDIT:**

> Active Directory error '80040e37'
>
> An invalid directory pathname was passed

Is the error message given when I do manage to pass one with Special Characters.

Comment: Why would you ever create a DN of such a format?

Comment: The DN is set when creating the group of course, and while i might not create one is such funky format, it's not far-fetched that we would use slashes, hash's or the ampersand. We also occasionally use quotation marks. e.g: All in Team Leaders (Ohio), All "Happy" employees. (Terrible group examples, but we do use those characters!)
We also use the @ symbol.

While it would be easy to limit the characters used, that's too late when we're operating a few thousand groups already. (Renaming is not an option at this point)

Any ideas about special character escaping to this level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to escape the string according to [RFC 4515 String Representation of Search Filters](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515.txt)

Generally, you need to escape the items listed in [RFC 4515 String Representation of Search Filters](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515.txt) and I would suggest, also any non-UTF8 character.

I also found some [methods that may be helpful](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm) to get your started.

I believe the proper escaped value you are trying to find is:
All in 463"567y\5c22"\c2\a4&/2#%&! Test Group

Finally, quit it.
Start populating an searching for Description or some other non-naming attribute. (any attribute that is not part of the DN) Make your DNs never changing. No user should ever see a DN which should be only a path to an entry. You will have issues with many "off-the-shelve" tools if you continue this practice.

I tried and was not even able to create the entry in two different vendors tools.

Comment: This was the push in the right direction I needed! To solve it, I compared the ADSI Edit strings with the ones given by "managedBy", noted the characters that were different, read your links regarding what is escaped and how, and finally escaped only the character "/" (to "\/"). I now have a list made of gibberish actually being found via LDAP.

Thanks!